# Need help to finding error line in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, error-handling, ide, spyder

I use Spyder IDE, but most of the time I can not find the line that the error occurred easily. For example this is one of those errrors:

```
runfile('C:/Users/m/Desktop/python/third.py', wdir='C:/Users/m/Desktop/python')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-1-22ecdcbaada4>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/m/Desktop/python/third.py', wdir='C:/Users/m/Desktop/python')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/m/Desktop/python/third.py", line 134
    predicted_stock_price = (predicted_stock_price + 1) *
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I understand which line of code caused the error? Why this IDE doesn't show the error line simply like other IDEs?

EDIT: It seems the rule of last line that some friends mentioned in comments doesn't work all the time. For example for this new error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/m/Desktop/python/third.py', wdir='C:/Users/m/Desktop/python')
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-22ecdcbaada4>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/m/Desktop/python/third.py', wdir='C:/Users/m/Desktop/python')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/m/Desktop/python/third.py", line 45, in <module>
    r = s.get('https://platform.tgju.org/fa/tvdata/history?symbol=AFGHAN_USD&resolution=60&from=1556027700&to=1561211760' , json = data ).json()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

Comment: The error Traceback shows you how Python got to this problem, from the beginning of the program, i.e. the functions being called, in that order. Normally the error is shown in the last line, in your case, File `third.py`, line 134, `predicted_stock_price = (predicted_stock_price + 1) * `, I think you've missed something after this `*`

Comment: @UdonN00dle: So you say I can find the error line at the last line all the time?

Comment: Normally yes, if it's a small syntax error or spelling error, but not always, if you're sure the last line is ok, then I would recommend to check from the bottom to the top, to see what are the values in each variables and what are the operations being done, next step is to set break-points and fire up the debug mode

Comment: I wish in next update they simply jump(point) to the error line automatically like almost all other IDES.

Comment: yeah the last line contains your error.

Comment: @JainilPatel: Thanks, but I meant about all the errors not just this example.

Comment: yeah once you start using, you will get use to it.

Comment: i know the traceback is worst.

Comment: sometimes its in the middle also .

Comment: The traceback is produced by Python, not by Spyder. Can you give an example of an IDE that behaves the way you want when executing Python code?

Comment: @nekomatic, thanks for pointing that out. I was about to ask the same.